# How to Append a combination field into nested list using Jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, nested-lists

Below is sample dataset (Could extract them as a dict if that's easier as I'm using Ansible `read_csv`)

```
[
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "apple",
            "quantity": "10",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "orange",
            "quantity": "20",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "carrot",
            "quantity": "5",
            "type": "veg"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "beetroot",
            "quantity": "2",
            "type": "veg"
        }
]
```

I needed to append a combination field including `type-name-id` combo to the nested list
So the final outcome expected is

```
[
        {
            "uid": "fruit-apple-1",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "apple",
            "quantity": "10",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
            "uid": "fruit-orange-2",
            "id": "2",
            "name": "orange",
            "quantity": "20",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        ...
```

The list is pretty large and hence avoiding the ansible loop and using plain Jinja.
I've tried below, but below pivots into a list of combination field ONLY. But I wanted to retain the nesting rather than a flat list

```
        - jinja_list: |-
            {% set uid = [] %}
            {% for item in fruits_csv_list.list %}
            {% set li = item.type + '-' +  item.name + '-' +  item.id %}
            {{uid.append(li)}}
            {%- endfor %}
            {{uid}}
```

Any idea how to achieve it efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to combine the current item with the k/v you need for the current uid. In a nutshell:

```yaml
    jinja_list: |-
      {% set result = [] %}
      {% for item in fruits_csv_list.list %}
      {% set li = {'uid': [item.type, item.name, item.id] | join('-')} %}
      {{ result.append(item | combine(li)) }}
      {%- endfor %}
      {{ result }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the list

```yaml
  f_list:
    - {id: '1', name: apple, quantity: '10', type: fruit}
    - {id: '2', name: orange, quantity: '20', type: fruit}
    - {id: '3', name: carrot, quantity: '5', type: veg}
    - {id: '4', name: beetroot, quantity: '2', type: veg}
```

---

Create the list of *uid*, *zip* the lists, and combine the dictionaries

```yaml
  f_uid: "{{ f_list|zip(f_list|json_query(q_uid))|map('combine') }}"
  q_uid: '[].{uid: [type, name, id]|join(`-`, @)}'
```

gives

```yaml
  f_uid:
    - {id: '1', name: apple, quantity: '10', type: fruit, uid: fruit-apple-1}
    - {id: '2', name: orange, quantity: '20', type: fruit, uid: fruit-orange-2}
    - {id: '3', name: carrot, quantity: '5', type: veg, uid: veg-carrot-3}
    - {id: '4', name: beetroot, quantity: '2', type: veg, uid: veg-beetroot-4}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    f_list:
      - {id: '1', name: apple, quantity: '10', type: fruit}
      - {id: '2', name: orange, quantity: '20', type: fruit}
      - {id: '3', name: carrot, quantity: '5', type: veg}
      - {id: '4', name: beetroot, quantity: '2', type: veg}

    f_uid: "{{ f_list|zip(f_list|json_query(q_uid))|map('combine') }}"
    q_uid: '[].{uid: [type, name, id]|join(`-`, @)}'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: f_uid|to_yaml
```